# Android OpenGL ES rendering subdivided Mesh

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to render a subdivided mesh with a displacement texture on it and a color texture. To do so I go through every pixel, create a vertex for it, and move that vertex according to a black and white image I have. The problem is that when I render it, I get something that looks a bit like TV snow. [image]

Here's the relevant code:

```
public Plane(Bitmap image, Bitmap depth)
{
    this.image = image; //color image
    this.depth = depth; //BW depth image
    this.w = image.getWidth();
    this.h = image.getHeight();

    vertexCoords = vertexArray(); //places vertices in 3d
    drawOrder = orderArray(); //sets the draw order
    colorCoords = colorArray(); //sets color per vertex

    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexCoords.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertexCoords);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(drawOrder.length * 4);
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
    drawListBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer cbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colorCoords.length * 4);
    cbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    colorBuffer = cbb.asFloatBuffer();
    colorBuffer.put(colorCoords);
    colorBuffer.position(0);
}

public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    // Counter-clockwise winding.
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
    // Enable face culling.
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    // What faces to remove with the face culling.
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);

    // Enabled the vertices buffer for writing and to be used during
    // rendering.
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    // Specifies the location and data format of an array of vertex
    // coordinates to use when rendering.
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);

    // Enable the color array buffer to be used during rendering.
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY); // NEW LINE ADDED.
    // Point out the where the color buffer is.
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer); // NEW LINE ADDED.

    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
            GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

    // Disable the vertices buffer.
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    // Disable face culling.
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}
```

What can I do to actually view the model, instead of this snow thing? The patterns change if I turn my screen on and off, and they sometimes change randomly. It seems that the colors present in the original bitmap are also present in the snow (the snow color changes with different pictures), so I know I'm doing something right, I just don't know what's wrong here.

EDIT: here's the code for `vertexArray()`

```
public float[] vertexArray()
{
    int totalPoints = w*h;
    float[] arr = new float[totalPoints*3];

    int i = 0;
    for(int y = 0; y<h; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x<w; x++)
        {
            arr[i] = x * 0.01f;
            arr[i+1] = y * 0.01f;
            arr[i+2] = 1.0f;//getDepth(x,y);
            i+=3;
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: `vertexCoords = vertexArray();` Is this correct? It looks like you are allocating a `vertexArray`, etc. but not putting anything in it, and thus not rendering any primitives.

Comment: `vertexArray()` is a function that takes the bitmap and puts the points in the right place. It returns `float[]`

Comment: What's the code for that? Additionally, how are you setting up your transformation matrices, if any?

Comment: I put up the code for vertexArray(). I used the transformation matrices from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/projection.html#transform), but it happened even before I used them.